# Magento Enterprise Editon URL rewrite

Tags: magento-enterprise, url

IN some scenario for configurable product , when we update the url-key , it is storing in the "catalog_product_entity_url_key" but in the admin panel it is the old key , we also flushed the cache and did reindexing from shell, still it is showing the same  url-key .

Now when we update the description it throws error

**Product with the '-------' url_key attribute already exists.**

If we update the url-key and the description it gets updated , but url-key is still the same .

Comment: How do you update the URL-Key? Only via admin panel? Which version of Magento EE are you using?

Comment: HI , updating the url key from admin panel ,the version of magento is  1.14.0.1

Answer (score 2):

If your EE is newer then 13, you should also update table `*enterprise_url_rewrite*` 
and set value for field ***`identifier`*** equal to *`catalog_product_entity_url_key`.**`value`***

Answer (score 2):

If if delete from **catalog_product_entity_varchar** the  **value** whose attribute id is url_key i.e., 97 and store id is 1, its solving the issue.